# C++ Try-Catch Statement not catching an exception

Tags: c++, try-catch, c++17

I am programming a very simple unit test framework in C++ that uses try-catch statements to analyze variables.  In this example I have the class titled `UnitTest` with one public and one private member-function titled `scalars_are_equal()` and `is_equal()` respectively.  The user must pass `str` to the public function, which contains a string with the name of the test.  The user must also pass `value1` and `value2` to the public function which contain two scalar values to be compared against each other.  The public function uses a `try` statement and passes the data to the private function where the two variables are evaluated to see if they match.  If the values match then it returns to the calling function where a message is printed to the screen to let the user know that the test passes.  If the values are not equal, then the private function should throw an exception assigned to the string `msg` and the public function should catch this exception.  The class is attached below.  The functions are written as template function so the user can choose to compare integers, floats and doubles, even though the floating point arithmetic may mean that two versions of a number are not exactly identical.

```
class UnitTest
{
public:
    template <class type1, class type2>
    void scalars_are_equal(std::string str, const type1 &value1, const type2 &value2);
private:
    template <class type1, class type2>
    void is_equal(const type1 &value1, const type2 &value2, std::string str);
};
// ================================================================
// ================================================================
// UnitTest PUBLIC member functions
template <class type1, class type2>
void UnitTest::scalars_are_equal(std::string str, const type1 &value1,
                             const type2 &value2)

{
    unsigned long remain;
    remain = 60 - str.length();
    try {
        is_equal(value1, value2, str);
        std::cout << str + std::string(remain, '.') +
        std::string("PASSED") << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const char* msg) {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------

template <class type1, class type2>
void UnitTest::is_equal(const type1 &value1, const type2 &value2,
                        std::string str)
{
    if (value1 != value2) {
        unsigned long remain;
        remain = 60 - str.length();
        std::string msg = str + std::string(remain, '.') + " FAILED";
        throw msg;
    }
```

}

In this case the main program looks like;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

#include "unit_test.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    UnitTest q;
{    // Test to see if code catches unequal scalars
    float a, b;
    a = 20.0;
    b = 30.0;
    std::string c ("Scalars_Unequal_Test");
    q.scalars_are_equal(c, a, b);
}
```

For reasons that I don't understand, the `catch` statement in the function `scalars_are_equal()` is not catching the `is_equal()` function.  At first I thought it might be because the function throws a `std::string`, but when I changed the catch statement from a const char to std::string, it did not make a difference.  Does anyone know why this is not catching the exception?

Comment: You really don't need all of that code to  [show the issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6134b17a5ab7ad9b).  Hint:  a `std::string` is not a `const char *`.

Comment: *but when I changed the catch statement from a const char to std::string, it did not make a difference* -- Please post this attempt.

Comment: Able to reproduce the `const char *`, but this is the expected behaviour. Unable to reproduce the `std::string` version. The changes I had to make to the code to get it compiling may have changed something. Can we get a [mcve] to try out on our own?

Comment: On a sort of unrelated note: This is not really what try and catch is for. Try and catch is for catching and recovering from errors, not passing data back and forth, which is what it appears you're doing.

Comment: @Chipster I'd say throwing an exception for a unit test failure is quite reasonable, this is the way many unit testing frameworks work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are throwing a std::string and not char* in  UnitTest::is_equal().

```
std::string msg = str + std::string(remain, '.') + " FAILED";
throw msg;
```

So you have to catch a string:

```
catch (std::string& msg) {
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Important side note: Don't throw std::string or similar but classes derived from std::exception or your own exception base class. For example:

```
 std::string msg = str + std::string(remain, '.') + " FAILED";
 throw std::runtime_error(msg);
 [...]
 catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type in your catch has to be the same as the type that you are throwing (or a parent class of that type).

Your code essentially boils down to

```
try
{
  throw std::string( "test" );
}
catch ( const char* msg )
{
}
```

You are throwing `std::string` but catching `const char*` so the exception is not caught. You need to either throw `"test"` directly without wrapping it in a `std::string` or change your catch to `std::string&`.

Throwing any kind of pointer type leads to ownership issues, who is responsible for freeing the pointer? For example in your code if you "fixed" the issue by calling `throw msg.c_str()` the `msg` string would be destroyed before your catch block is reached and the `char*` pointer would be invalid, to fix that you'd have to dynamically allocate a new `char` array and copy `msg` into it, the `catch` block would then need to `delete` the array but has no way of knowing that it needs to.

Throwing arbitrary types is allowed by the language but it is recommended to derive all your throw types from `std::exception`, this then allows you to write code like the following and be able to capture all the exceptions thrown by your code.

```
try
{
  // lots of code including calling third party libraries
}
catch ( std::exception& ex )
{
  std::cout << "uncaught exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
}
```

Exception types are usually caught by reference as this avoids copying them into the catching context and also avoids slicing issues with derived classes.